# process numerical input arguments of mixed ints, floats, and "array-like" things of same length>1

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, converting

I'm trying to process numerical input arguments for a function. Users can mix ints, floats, and "array-like" things of ints and float, as long as they are all length=1 or the same length>1.

Now I convert them as follows:

```
convert to float                                convert to np.ndarray; dtype==float
----------------                                -----------------------------------
float  
int
np.float64
range object resulting in len == 1              range object resulting in len > 1
len==1 list or tuple of int or float            len > 1 list or tuple of ints & floats
len==1 np.ndarray of dtype np.int or np.float   len > 1 np.ndarray of dtype np.int or np.float
```

then test all resulting arrays to make sure they are the same length. If so, I return a list containing floats and arrays. If not, return `None`.

I want to avoid up-conversion of booleans and small byte-length ints.

The script below appears to do what I want by brute force testing, but I wonder if there is a better way?

---

Desired behaviors:

- `fixem(some_bad_things)` returns `None`
- `fixem(all_good_things)` returns `[42.0, 3.14, 3.141592653589793, 2.718281828459045, 3.0, 42.0, 3.0, 42.0, array([1. , 2.3, 2. ]), array([3.14, 1.  , 4.  ]), array([1., 2., 2.]), array([3., 1., 4.]), array([0., 1., 2.]), array([0, 1, 2])]`
- and `sum(fixem(all_good_things))` returns `array([149.13987448 149.29987448 156.99987448])`

---

```
def fixit(x):
    result = None
    if type(x) in (int, float, np.float64):
        result = float(x)
    elif type(x) == range:
        y = list(x)
        if all([type(q) in (int, float) for q in y]):
            if len(y) == 1:
                result = float(y[0])
            elif len(y) > 1:
                result = np.array(y)
    elif type(x) in (tuple, list) and all([type(q) in (int, float) for q in x]):
        y = np.array(x)
        if y.dtype in (int, float):
            if len(y) == 1:
                result = float(y[0])
            elif len(y) > 1:
                result = y.astype(float)
    elif (type(x) == np.ndarray and len(x.shape) == 1 and
          x.dtype in (np.int, np.float)):
        if len(x) == 1:
            result = float(x[0])
        elif len(x) > 1:
            result = x.astype(float)
    return result

def fixem(things):
    final = None
    results = [fixit(thing) for thing in things]
    floats  = [r for r in results if type(r) is float]
    arrays  = [r for r in results if type(r) is np.ndarray]
    others  = [r for r in results if type(r) not in (float, np.ndarray)]
    if len(others) == 0:
        if len(arrays) == 0 or len(set([len(a) for a in arrays]))==1: # none or all same length
            final = floats + arrays
    return final

import numpy as np

some_bad_things = ('123', False, None, True, 42, 3.14, np.pi, np.exp(1),
                   [1, 2.3, 2], (3.14, 1, 4), [1, 2, 2], (3, 1, 4),
                   (3,), [42], (3.,), [42.], np.array([True, False]),
                   np.array([False]), np.array(False), np.array('xyz'),
                   np.array(42), np.array(42.), np.arange(3.), range(3))

all_good_things = (42, 3.14, np.pi, np.exp(1), [1, 2.3, 2], (3.14, 1, 4),
                   [1, 2, 2], (3, 1, 4), (3,), [42], (3.,), [42.],
                   np.arange(3.), range(3))

for i, things in enumerate((some_bad_things, all_good_things)):
    print(i, fixem(things))

print(sum(fixem(all_good_things))) # confirm
```

Comment: I'm curious, where does this problem come from?

Comment: @Georgy I don't understand exactly how to answer your question. I'm writing a script for others to use that will do a calculation based on numerical input. If they are all floats, it will perform a calculation and return one object; if one or more are array-like, it returns a collection of them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. I suggest using `isinstance` instead of `type` to check the types of variables. You can read about it in details here: [What are the differences between type() and isinstance()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1549801/7851470)
   So, for example, instead of writing:

   ```
   if type(x) in (int, float, np.float64):
   ```

   you would write:

   ```
   if isinstance(x, (int, float)):
   ```

   You can check that it works for `np.exp(1)` which is of type `np.float64`.
2. When the `x` is of type `range` the following check is redundant:

   ```
   if all([type(q) in (int, float) for q in y])
   ```

   as the elements of `y` will be always integers. Also, there is no need to convert `range` to `list`. The following will also work:

   ```
   result = float(x[0]) if len(x) == 1 else np.array(x)
   ```
3. To check if a list is empty in Python we usually write:

   ```
   if not others:
   ```

   instead of:

   ```
   if len(others) == 0:
   ```
4. Imports should be at the top of the script. Move the `import numpy as np` line there.
5. In the future, when you have a function that can accept variables of different types and its behavior depends on which type it gets, you could try using [`singledispatch`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functools.html#functools.singledispatch). I could come up with the following implementation:

   ```
   from collections.abc import Iterable
   from functools import singledispatch
   from numbers import Real

   import numpy as np


   @singledispatch
   def fixit(x):
       return None

   @fixit.register
   def _(x: Real):
       return float(x)


   @fixit.register
   def _(x: Iterable):
       y = np.array(x)
       if y.dtype in (np.int, np.float) and len(y.shape) == 1:
           return float(y[0]) if len(y) == 1 else y.astype(float)
       else:
           return None
   ```

   I didn't check it thoroughly but for your test cases it works. (but looks a bit ugly)
6. A better way to solve your problem would be to convert immediately all the values to NumPy arrays of at least one dimension. We would require a [`np.atleast_1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.atleast_1d.html) function for that:

   ```
   def to_normalized_data(values):
       arrays = list(map(np.atleast_1d, values))
       sizes = set(map(np.size, arrays))
       has_bad_types = any(array.dtype not in (np.int32, np.float64) for array in arrays)
       if len(sizes) > 2 or has_bad_types:
           return None
       max_size = max(sizes)
       singletons = [float(array[0]) for array in arrays if array.size == 1]
       iterables = [array.astype(float) for array in arrays if array.size == max_size]
       return singletons + iterables
   ```

   ```
   >>> to_normalized_data(all_good_things)
   [42.0,
    3.14,
    3.141592653589793,
    2.718281828459045,
    3.0,
    42.0,
    3.0,
    42.0,
    array([1. , 2.3, 2. ]),
    array([3.14, 1.  , 4.  ]),
    array([1., 2., 2.]),
    array([3., 1., 4.]),
    array([0., 1., 2.]),
    array([0., 1., 2.])]
   >>> sum(to_normalized_data(all_good_things))
   array([149.13987448, 149.29987448, 156.99987448])
   >>> print(to_normalized_data(some_bad_things))
   None
   ```

---

**Answering your comments:**

1. > For some reason my anaconda's numpy (1.17.3) returns int64 rather than
   >   int32 as you have in item 6

   Looks like this behavior is [OS-specific](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36278590/7851470). Probably a better way to check the types of the obtained arrays would be by using [`np.can_cast`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.can_cast.html). So, instead of writing:

   ```
   has_bad_types = any(array.dtype not in (np.int32, np.float64) for array in arrays)
   ```

   we could write:

   ```
   has_bad_types = not all(np.can_cast(array.dtype, np.float64) for array in arrays)
   ```
2. > Item #6 doesn't reject two different lengths if no singletons are present. With `([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4])` as input, the output is `[array([1., 2., 3., 4.])]` and `[1, 2, 3]` just falls through the cracks and disappears

   Welp, I missed this case... We can add it back as:

   ```
   if len(sizes) > 2 or 1 not in sizes or has_bad_types:
   ```
3. > also my original script tested if `len(x.shape) == 1` in order to reject ndm > 1 arrays which item #6 doesn't, but that can be easily added back with something like testing for `set(map(np.ndim, arrays)) == set((1,))`. This is important because `np.size` won't distinguish between a length=4 1D array and a 2x2 array.

   Yep, that's right. Taking all the above into account, the final code could look like this:

   ```
   def to_normalized_data(values):
       arrays = list(map(np.atleast_1d, values))
       sizes = set(map(np.size, arrays))
       have_bad_types = not all(np.can_cast(array.dtype, np.float64) for array in arrays)
       have_several_dimensions = set(map(np.ndim, arrays)) > {1}
       if len(sizes) > 2 or 1 not in sizes or have_bad_types or have_several_dimensions:
           return None
       max_size = max(sizes)
       singletons = [float(array[0]) for array in arrays if array.size == 1]
       iterables = [array.astype(float) for array in arrays if array.size == max_size]
       return singletons + iterables
   ```

Comment: fyi I've just asked [Managing user defined and default values for instance attributes](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/233319/145009)

Comment: Bingo! Excellent, thank you for your time and effort!